# Beginner-flat topology for Balustrade

Tags: topology

Just starting out and am trying to figure out the best topology for the attached. I can certainly mirror from the arch centre, but having difficulty with where to start. From left to right within the larger opening and 'cloverleaf'... or from the right to left with the simpler edges of the block? The triangular divots against the outer arch bevels are also complicating my attempts to reduce.

Thoughts/comments welcome, and thanks in advance for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First begin with the outlines, then extrude on the Y axis, then scale the extrusion, bring some additional edge loops to bring details and sharpen the edges, etc...

[image]

Comment: Bravo! And here I am trying to move the default cube...

Comment: mmh I don't believe you  ;)

Comment: Whoa... thank you M. Good to go.